# Is adding an article's ID as a hidden input without making sure it exists at server side considered bad practice?

Tags: php, mysql, html, security

lets say I have the following tables:
1. `comments` : `c_id`, `a_id`, `body`
2. `articles` : `a_id`, `title`, `body`

I have a comments system(similar to SO). But ofcource I have to provide the article's Id that being posted on, and there's many ways of doing that.

So, I went with the simple method, which is creating a hidden input with the ID of the article, just like this:
  `<input type="hidden" name="article_id" value="1" />`
 then simply it's POSTed to the server-side. and inserted to the table using MySQL.   But, isn't it possible for a bad user to change the data in the hidden input?

For example if he change the hidden input and put an invalid ID, or an article that doesn't exist or anything that I really don't need. Is that something I should consider? since the only thing that will happen is invalid comment, nothing more. since I'm getting the `intval` of all integer inputs, I'm not afraid of any type of SQL injection.

Bottom line: Should I really care about invalid comments, and issue an extra query checking if an article exists first, which will take more resources, just to make sure no invalid harmless comments will be inserted.

Comment: It doesn't matter what type of input it is. All that is sent to your server is `article_id=1`.

Comment: Ideally you should have a foreign-key relationship in the database so that the comments table *can't* refer to nonexistent article IDs.  (But that's a last line of defense; the application should still check, rather than relying on the database to do it, since the application can handle the situation more gracefully.)

Comment: @Wyzard I'm using MyISAM engine. I heard it doesn't support foreign keys, am I right?

Comment: Probably not.  It doesn't support transactions either.  Don't use MyISAM if you care about the integrity of your database.

Comment: I dont know all the differences between myISAM and innoDB but really, unless you need high scalibility and superb performace (most people don't) just switch the engine to InnoDB. Really the only advantage that  I know of for myISAM is the full text search

Comment: MyISAM offers "superb performance" because it doesn't bother with any of that reliability or integrity stuff.  :-)

Comment: true, although another great advantage of innodb is that it has row locking vs table of myISAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always check to make sure the user isn't inserting bad/invalid data.

NEVER trust the client. It is extremely easy to change the hidden value

Now you should have foriegn key constraints in your db which will partly protect you from this, however if they change the article id to something that is valid, but maybe they don't have access to (article is locked) you want to protect vs that

Comment: I never trust the client, that's why I'm using intval but, what would happen if a user enters 9999 as an article ID? is this something I should be worried about?

Comment: Well depends, if that article id exists and the client has access to it.. then no. But if say you want to lock certain articles from allowing people to post comments to that article, then you will want to defend that. I also updated my question regarding foreign key constraints that you should set up in your tables

Answer (score 1):

You are 100% correct that the user can change the data. Bottom-line is, anything on the client-side can be modified by the client (good or bad).

I would definitely validate the ID coming from the client regardless as to how you're using it. Inserting invalid IDs into the database should technically fail if you have proper foreign-key relationships setup, but assuming you don't then it could lead to a database full of invalid data.

Additionally, if you keep track of all "invalid" IDs that are submitted and what user submitted them you can (in the future) implement logic that can block/ban users from posting comments, among other things.